# Responsive Navbar with Dropdown don't show dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, navbar, dropdown, responsive

I have to put a respnsive menu with submenus.
I found this lesson : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp

The menu itself comes out, but when I click the "Dropdown" button, the submenus are not displayed at all.I tried to change some code but nothing get.

How can I fix this or where to look for the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
```

```css
#navbaronder {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  margin: 155px 0px 0px 0px;  /* viso4ina na drop down menuto*/
  transition: 0.4s;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 500;
 
  
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
 <style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>

<div id="navbaronder">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown 
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: The submenu (with Link 1, Link 2...) is visible, when you move your mouse over Dropdown. It is just invisible in the snipped here, because of the margin-top set to 155px. That moves the dropdown outside the visible area. Is this your problem?

Comment: When I place the menu on my website and hover over it, the submenus are invisible / not displayed.

I solved the problem by changing in CSS - .dropdown-content - from position: absolute; to position: fixed; .